# How can you pass configuration options to flat pickr in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date

I have this form where I'm trying to implement [flatpickr.js](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#datetimepicker-with-limited-time-range) . I've managed to get the calendar working and it saves the date as expected, but I can't seem to make it use the configuration options I'm passing in the dataset (I specifically need to be able to select time in addition to dates).

This is the input field HTML:

```
<%= f.text_field :authorized_at, data: { controller: "flatpickr", attributes: {enableTime: true, dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i"} }, placeholder: "aaaa-mm-dd" , class: "form-control" %>
```

And in the flatpickr.js controller I have this:

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';

export default class extends Controller {

    connect() {
    let config = this.element.dataset.attributes
    console.log("Hello flatpickr")
    flatpickr(this.element, {config});
  }
}
```

Console logging `this.element.dataset.attributes` effectively returns a hash with the corresponding options, but the calendar in the View does not display the time picker.

Any hints on what am I missing?

I manage to make it work by passing the options directly in the controller hash like so:

```
flatpickr(this.element, {enableTime: true, dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i"});
```

But storing the attributes dataset in a variable and passing that doesn't work.

EDIT: Ok so the problem was that the attributes dataset was sending the keys as strings, whereas it expected a js object.

So I had to call JSON.parse and pass the dataset to convert it back again and it worked:

```
    connect() {
    let config = JSON.parse(this.element.dataset.attributes)
    console.log("Hello flatpickr")
    flatpickr(this.element, config);
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know you have to pass a class name as the first argument not the element itself.

Comment: I managed to make it work by using the options directly in the controller hash. But passing a variable to it storing the hash of options doesn't work.

Comment: maybe because you wrapped the config variable in `{}` itself. so in the end you had a hash inside a hash?

Comment: because storing information in a variable shouldn't work differently than passing it directly

Comment: I'm suspecting that's the problem. But I'm trying to use the variable config without the {} and it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, passing the options directly in the controller I'm using symbols {enableTime: true, dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i"}); whereas console logging the dataset returns strings instead of symbols {"enableTime":true,"dateFormat":"Y-m-d H:i"} . Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Yep that's got to be it. You could transfer them from strings into symbols if you want to stay flexible and reuse the controller maybe for another input where you don't need the time or so

Comment: I used JSON.parse to convert the attributes dataset to a js object and now it works. Thanks.